# How to use Blend to create a basic Grid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

I'm a developer who's trying to get the hang of Blend.  I've always used Blend to mess with control templates and such, but I'm trying to get the hang of using it for basic UI design, since I figure it's probably a bit faster than typing the XAML up manually in Visual Studio.

Right now I'm just trying to create a basic Grid, but I'm seeing two default behaviors that I'm hoping someone can show me how to change.

1)  When I hover my mouse outside of the design surface, I see the temporary yellow line to show up, where the new Grid Column / Row will be when I click.  The problem is that the newly created rows are set to heights like 0.2297*  How do I get Blend to attach regular heights, like 250?

2)  Ignoring 1), once I have some rows and columns, when I drag a button, or combo box, etc, onto one of the cells, it drops it **exactly** where I release the mouse, while adding some large margins to position it there.  Is it possible to tell blend to just drop the control into the cell, and leave the margins alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grids are awesome but it takes a bit of play to get proficient at working with them in Blend.  Here are some tips to get you started (I cover this in detail in chapter 4 of [my book](http://manning.com/cochran/)).

1) When you use the snap lines to create rows and columns Blend automatically makes them relative (Star) sized, which is the behavior you are seeing. To change the row/column style to fixed (Pixel) sizes, click on the Padlock icons to the left and top of the desired rows and columns.  Then, either edit the values in XAML or you can click near (but not on) the padlock to select the row or column.  This will open the sizing properties in the Properties panel.

2) The short answer is "No".  Blend will always add Margins when you draw the element in a cell unless you take care to draw them to the borders.  This is too difficult and time consuming, so I just make sure I draw it somewhere inside my target cell.  Now I can right-click the element and select "Auto Size > Fill" and the element will fill up the cell: no Margins, Width and Height set to Auto, and Horizontal and Vertical Alignments set to Stretch.  [FWIW, addressing this is my number one feature request for Blend.]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well it resolves it, that's for sure.  It's a bit of a let down though, to be honest.  For #2 having your textboxes and buttons expand to auto-fill isn't much better than the status quo.  I wish I could talk to someone on the Blend team to hear what they were thinking when they designed this "feature".  Thank you for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: I don't understand your response RE the auto-fill, does that not do what you were after?  I mean, I know it doesn't happen on Drop, but were you looking for a different result?  If not, it is better than needing to set all 5 properties yourself...

Comment: I would expect dropping a button into a cell to simply create a plain old button in that cell, with no margins, positioning it by default at the top left.  Wouldn't that be the most appropriate default?  Wouldn't you normally just do that, then adjust the grid by altering row/column sizes, with maybe an occasional margin when needed?  Putting in specific margins to drop the button precisely where your mouse happens to be seems awful to me, since nothing would ever line up at first, since you're bound to have your mouse in just a little bit different place each time.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Your answer is correct, don't get me wrong, I was just remarking that the blend design doesn't really make sense to me on this feature, but maybe I'm just missing something bigger.  And auto-filling your buttons and textboxes might work, but wouldn't your rows and columns have to be the exact right size, to prevent your controls from seeming either too big and bloated, or else shrunk?

Comment: RE Comment 1: Now I understand what you are saying. The difference comes in whether or not you are dropping on the Artboard.  When you drop it that way, it uses the mouse position to set the Margin.  You can avoid the Margins by double clicking form the Toolbar on the left (with the Grid the active container), but you must then manually set the correct row and column.  I prefer the drop approach when dealing with Grids.

Comment: RE Comment 2: Yes, you are absolutely correct!  In fact, this is one of the core tenets of my "Container Driven Design" approach.  I use Auto-Fill to make the child elements "greedy" and control their size and positions using the parent container.  In this case, the container is a Grid cell.  This works very well for Fluid layout, and I only worry about sizing and resizing the appropriate parent containers.

Comment: I see what you mean about selecting the grid in the objects and timelines panel, then double clicking on a button; it always puts it in the 0,0 cell.  I don't suppose there's a way to select a particular cell in the O and T panel?  That would be really cool, but I'm guessing it's not possible.

Comment: I'll have to buy your book, but I guess I'm having trouble imagining how this greedy grid-based control sizing could work in a non-trivial example.  I just imagine the classic grid of textboxes and labels, where some textboxes are smaller than others based on the data they're collecting.  IE a "comments" box would be multi-line, and very wide, so this control would have to have a row all to itself, otherwise anything else in the row would be stretched much too tall, wouldn't it?

Comment: BTW - I just finished Andrew Troelsen's Apress offering of Blend 4.  One thing he was really missing was MVVM from the perspective of how it affects Blend.  In other words, he wasted a lot of space showing the fake data generation "stuff" Blend has, but didn't really show how to use the ViewModel locater pattern to connect a real ViewModel, with network services wired in at runtime, versus a "fake" ViewModel, with mocked data that Blend will show you to help design more easily, at design time.

Comment: RE comment 1: Yes, that would be cool! I'll add it to my wish list :-)

Comment: RE comment 2: there are several ways to solve that, but first I would say don't think of Grid in terms of data/table, think of it in terms of app layout.  Also, I teach using nested containers, so in the case you mentioned you could use a StackPanel (in a Grid cell) for variable width content.  There's also nothing saying you can't use Margins, but they are for visual effect opposed to layout (so that fits your scenario as well)

Comment: RE comment 3: I have an appendix that covers MVVM from the Blend perspective, primarily as a pre-cursor to understanding data binding in Blend.  It isn't the end-all-be-all of MVVM, that was way beyond the scope of the book (so nothing like ViewModelLocator is covered).  I do also cover sample data, but only briefly as it is not a preference of mine.

Comment: Nested containers makes a lot of sense - I can see where that would solve the issue I pointed out.  Thanks for all your time; I wish I could give you more than one upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

To answer point 1) Blend is creating proportional grids so that the columns remain the same relative widths when you grow or shrink the grid rather than absolute grids. So if you want absolute grid widths you'll have to go in and edit the values by hand.

I find that it's easier to create the basic form in Blend and then tweak the values in the text editor - either in Visual Studio or Blend itself.

As for point 2) I've just tried this and as long as I click inside the column/row on the grid when placing a button it adds it to the correct column/row of the grid as expected. Select the button and then just double click inside the grid - this should add a button of default size where you clicked, but in the grid. (It would be much easier if I could see what you were doing).

Comment: Thank you, sorry to be obtuse, but can you elaborate #2?  I've tried clicking in the grid cell on the designer, then double clicking the button from my assets, clicking the cell then dragging, etc